# git branch off of another branch

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging

Hi I have two branches in parallel 'dev' and 'prod' I would like to add another local branch to the local dev branch called 'issue22' (GitPro refers to this as a **topic** branch - others call it a **feature** branch).  So at the terminal I created my feature/topic branch with

```
git checkout -b issue22 dev
```

Which I thought would do 'make a branch called issue22' and start with the same source code that is in the dev branch. I am expecting to see

```
prod
dev
dev/issue22
```

However when I send the command
    git branch -a

Instead, I see

```
prod
dev
issue22
remotes/origin/head -> origin/master
remotes/origin/dev
remotes/origin/prod
```

What command should I use to create a new branch so that 'issue22' appears to look like a **topic/feature** branch that runs in parallel to the 'dev' branch and also appears to stem from the dev branch?

many thanks

Comment: Your terminology is very confusing, can you please edit the question to show the exact commands and outputs, and the fully qualified branch names and repo names; since you seem to be using the word branch and repository interchangeably when they are not.

Comment: Case in point You can't add a branch to a branch. You can however add a branch to a repository.

Comment: Please research this site - http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ that is the model of "When starting work on a new feature, branch off from the develop branch." The whole point of git as far as i understand is to branch off of branches. yes, git only sees 'commits' - but I would like to be able to visualize branches running in parallel. I appreciate your input UpAndAdam, but I did not use the word 'repository' in my question. I am posting more commands & output...

Comment: If you use a branch visualization tool like `gitk` or `git log --all --graph --decorate` you should see that `issue22` and `dev` are in fact at the same place. This is the closest that Git gets to "branching off another branch". You can then work in `issue22` and commit to that branch. Then when you're done you can merge into `dev`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris - so does that mean that http://nvie.com/files/Git-branching-model.pdf is not a possible visualization when using git? I'm asking because I'm trying to make our git branch look like this (because it reads like a taxonomy hierarchy). Instead, when we make 'feature' and 'hot fix' branches, there is no hierarchy. It would be like you have one directory C:\ and you have to put all your folders (commits) in there. I'd like to have C:\Dev\fix1 C:\Prod\hotfix, instead what we have just looks like C:\prod C:\dev C:\fix1 etc.

Comment: @user1709076, you can definitely reproduce that diagram precisely with Git. Please see my answer; I hope it clears things up for you.

Comment: Also your typo'd command of `git branch -d issue22 dev` would actually DELETE the branches you named.  It won't create them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parental relationship between commits is what gives a repository its "structure". And a visualization like the one [displayed on the Git Flow website](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is definitely possible with Git. It was designed *around* Git!

Here is an example that should get you started:

1. First, create a new repository and add a single empty commit:

   ```
   $ mkdir test-repo && cd test-repo
   $ git init
   $ git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial empty commit"
   ```

   At this point you've got one branch and one commit. Your network will look something like

   ```
   [master]  A
   ```

   Here, `A` represents the blue dot at the extreme top-right corner of the Git-Flow site.
2. This commit is missing its tag from the diagram. Let's add it:

   ```
   $ git tag -a 0.1
   ```

   Now we've got

   ```
   [master] [0.1]  A
   ```
3. Now we'll create our `develop` branch:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b develop
   ```

   At this point, we *haven't added any commits to `develop` that aren't in `master`*, so the branches are pointing to the *exact same commit*:

   ```
   [master] [develop] [0.1]  A
   ```
4. It's getting a bit crowded here. Let's add a few more commits to `develop`:

   ```
   $ # Hack, hack, hack...
   $ git add somefile.txt otherfile.dat
   $ git commit
   $ # Hack, hack, hack...
   $ git add foo.bar
   $ git commit
   ```

   Now our network is a little bit more interesting. When we created each of these two new commits, our `develop` branch was updated to point to each of them in turn. Now we've got

   ```
   [master] [0.1]  A
                    \
   [develop]         B---C
   ```

   `develop` actually points to commit `C` at this point, and we can trace `C`'s ancestry back to commit `A`.
5. We can do the same thing with a new branch `issue22`, though it won't be named `develop/issue22` unless we explicitly call it that:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b issue22
   $ # Hack, hack, hack...
   $ git add foo.bar
   $ git commit
   ```

   and now we've got

   ```
   [master] [0.1]  A
                    \
   [develop]         B---C
                          \
   [issue22]               D
   ```

   `issue22` branches off of `develop` *by virtue of `D`'s parent being `C`*. We can do some more work on both `develop` and `issue22`

   ```
   [master] [0.1]  A
                    \
   [develop]         B---C---F---G
                          \
   [issue22]               D---E---H
   ```

   without changing that relationship. Then we can merge `issue22` back into `develop` (or directly into `master`, though that's not the "Git-FLow way") and get something like

   ```
   [master] [0.1]  A
                    \
   [develop]         B---C---F---G---I
                          \         /
   [issue22]               D---E---H
   ```

This model extends to as many branches as you'd like, and with a little care you could exactly reproduce the Git-Flow diagram. Branches don't "diverge" until they contain different commits.

It might be helpful for you to understand a little bit about Git's internal workings. The website [Think like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) is a very good introduction.

Comment: Thanks. A masterful and thoroughly explained answer. Very cool-headed and knowledgeable. You clearly understand this and I am grateful for your ability to communicate it to me. Many thanks.